# e.results.map is not a function in typescript3

Tags: typescript

here is my code :

Search.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import Suggestions from './Suggestions'

const API_KEY:string = "process.env"
const API_URL:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/v1/test'

export class Search extends React.Component{
  state = {
  query: '' as string,
    results : [] as any[]
  }
  search = {
    value: '' as string,
    }
  getInfo = () => {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/${this.state.query}/`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          results: data.data
        })
      })
  }

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      query: this.search.value
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
        if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
          this.getInfo()
        }
      } else if (!this.state.query) {
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          placeholder="Search for..."
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Suggestions results={this.state.results} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Search
```

and Suggestion.tsx :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { any } from 'prop-types';

export const Suggestions = (props:any) => {
  const options = props.results.map((r: { id: React.Key; name: React.ReactNode; }) => (
    <li key={r.id}>
      {r.name}
    </li>
  ))
  return <ul>{options}</ul>
}

export default Suggestions
```

but i get a Uncaught TypeError: e.results.map is not a function :

[image]

So the error is in mapping my result in suggestion but how to correct this ?

The result of the api is  :

> {'data': {'0': 'toto', '1': 'titi'}}

So i ddon't have any ideas on how to correct this error to map correctly the result of the call of the api to the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {'data': {'0': 'toto', '1': 'titi'}}

The `data` object you are accessing is not an array. Thus, you cannot directly use `Array` prototype methods (like `map`) on object literals.

You'll either need to return an array from your API or change your code to iterate over the object appropriately like:

```
for(key in obj) { 
    console.log(obj[key])
}
```

Comment: I suspect that your response data should be `{'data':[ {'0': 'toto', '1': 'titi'}] }`